# Shiny: dynamic dataframe construction; renderUI, observe, reactiveValues

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

i think the question of how to dynamically subset data using Shiny's renderUI functionality comes up every so often but i'm struggling to understand when to use renderUI (with uiOutput) over other functionality including observe, reactive, reactiveValues and even conditionalPanel.

I would like to build a fully interactive dataframe in which every choice influences what you can choose in the other inputs. For this example we will have a selectInput (single), selectInput (multi) and a sliderInput (with max & min).

The primary select, Category 1, can be any value in Category 1 or "All". By selecting something in Category 1, you in turn influence what can be shown in Category 2 and the range of values on the slider. By choosing Category 2 first, you restrict the options of Category 1 and also the values in the slider (which always represent the max and min of the subset). By starting with the sliderInput, Category 1 and Category 2 are limited if none of their data fall in the range you have stated.

N.B. i will incorporate a 'reset' actionButton to reset the dataframe to what it is when the app initialises.

an attempt using some dummy data, which I have not managed to get working. This will subset by Category 1 and update the slider but changing Category 2 will not overwrite the rendered table;

```
require(shiny)

    data <- data.frame(Category1 = rep(letters[1:3],each=15),
                       Info = paste("Text info",1:45),
                       Category2 = sample(letters[15:20],45,replace=T),
                       Size = sample(1:100, 45),
                       MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff",1:45))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("category1"),
      uiOutput("category2"),
      uiOutput("sizeslider")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  df_subset <- reactive({
    if(input$cat1=="All") {df_subset <- data}
    else{df_subset <- data[data$Category1==input$cat1,]}

  })

  df_subset1 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$cat2)){df_subset()} else {df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2==input$cat2,]}
  })

  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1', 'Choose Cat 1', choices = c("All",sort(as.character(unique(data$Category1)))),selected = "All")
  })

  output$category2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat2', 'Choose Cat 2 (optional):', choices = sort(as.character(unique(df_subset1()$Category2))), multiple = TRUE,options=NULL)
  })

  output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("size", label = "Size Range", min=min(df_subset1()$Size), max=max(df_subset1()$Size), value = c(min(df_subset1()$Size),max(df_subset1()$Size)))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_subset1()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit tricky to follow what is happening, however, is this what you want? Note changed the `reactive` into `eventReactive` so it is specifically bound to an `input`. Also I used the `%in%` operator to have multiple selects for your `selectizeInput`

**Edit: in your first code you dont even use the slider, I added it to filtering**

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(Category1 = rep(letters[1:3],each=15),
                   Info = paste("Text info",1:45),
                   Category2 = sample(letters[15:20],45,replace=T),
                   Size = sample(1:100, 45),
                   MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff",1:45))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("category1"),
      uiOutput("category2"),
      uiOutput("sizeslider")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1', 'Choose Cat 1', choices = c("All",sort(as.character(unique(data$Category1)))),selected = "All")
  })

  df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1,{
    if(input$cat1=="All") {df_subset <- data}
    else{df_subset <- data[data$Category1 == input$cat1,]}
  })

  df_subset1 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$cat2)){df_subset()} else {df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]}
  })

  output$category2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat2', 'Choose Cat 2 (optional):', choices = sort(as.character(unique(df_subset()$Category2))), multiple = TRUE,options=NULL)
  })

  output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("size", label = "Size Range", min=min(df_subset1()$Size), max=max(df_subset1()$Size), value = c(min(df_subset1()$Size),max(df_subset1()$Size)))
  })

  df_subset2 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$size)){df_subset1()} else {df_subset1()[df_subset1()$Size >= input$size[1] & df_subset1()$Size <= input$size[2],]}
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_subset2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't quite do it, the slider still has no effect on the output and the category2 choice does not update the rendered table (though you can see it do something before it promptly disappears)

Comment: You dont even use the slider in your example code, at least try it next time

Comment: thanks for your strangely aggressive help. I think it was an understandable oversight, and an oversight is all it was, to miss out the slider, there was quite a lot going on in the code. Thanks all the same.