# Shiny: dynamic dataframe construction; choose variables

Tags: r, shiny

I have one question to open the topic already. Well, I'm trying to do a similar app to this one [Shiny: dynamic dataframe construction; renderUI, observe, reactiveValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864881/shiny-dynamic-dataframe-construction-renderui-observe-reactivevalues). And I would like to add a new category at the beginning which will select the variables from the table. I'm going in the right direction?

```
Data <- reactive({

    if(input$table == "All"){df_subset <- data} 
    else{df_subset <- data[,input$show_vars,drop=FALSE]}

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
    Data <- reactive({
      req(input$table)
      if(input$table == "All"){
        return(data)
      } 
      else{
        df_subset <- data[,names(data) %in% input$show_vars]
      }
      df_subset
    })
```

or even shorter:

```
Data <- reactive({
  req(input$table)
  if(input$table == "All"){
    return(data)
  } 
  data[,names(data) %in% input$show_vars]
})
```

Comment: I use your code and ui: selectizeInput("show_vars", "Columns to show:", choices = colnames(data), multiple = TRUE,selected = c("Category1","Info","Category2")), but still not working